# Script tag in React throwing Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to add a script file to a jsx element.

The script file contains a simple `console.log('script ran')` and nothing else (I want to add an actual script file, but for testing purpose I chose this minimal code).

```
// editor.js

console.log('script ran')
```

```
// App.jsx

import React, { useEffect } from 'react'

const App = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const script = document.createElement('script')
    script.src = '/editor.js'
    document.body.appendChild(script)
  }, [])

  return <></>
}
```

This throws the error below

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' at editor.js 1:1
```

Folder Structure:

```
/
package.json
editor.js
src/
  App.js
  index.js
```

I have tried adding `type="text/javascript"`, `type="text/babel"`, `async=true` but nothing seems to work.

When I inspect the `editor.js` file in the developer tools, it shows an html file (The 404 page of my website)

When using `type="text/babel"` it doesnt throw any error, but also doesnt execute the script (console.log is never printed)

What am I doing wrong here?
Also, I would like a solution which doesnt use React Helmet

React version: 17.0.1 (created with create-react-app)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You never serve the script and it's not accessible from the browser.

When you try to access `/editor.js` you are getting `index.html`, because that's how webpack's config for react works.

You should move your script to [public](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/using-the-public-folder/)

```
const App = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const script = document.createElement('script')
    script.src = process.env.PUBLIC_URL + '/editor.js'
    document.body.appendChild(script)

    // remember to remove the script
    return () => script.remove()
  }, [])

  return <></>
}
```

You didn't say anything about what development server you are using, but I guess it's `create-react-app`

Comment: while is this likely very true (and I've +1'ed it), the bigger question in my head is "why manually include an external script dynamically inside a component?". Can't you just `import` the relevant parts of it into your `App.jsx` and use them there?

Comment: Probably not the case this time, but it can be useful sometimes with self-embedding scripts like this one `<script src="https://gist.github.com/KonradLinkowski/4dbaed1294a677d618c0b0ab03baf057.js"></script>` https://codepen.io/KonradLinkowski/pen/VwxVQxz I guess

Comment: @RobinZigmond, right. It was a third-party script so I didn't know I can include it like that.